# Understanding kotlin executors

Tags: java, kotlin, executor

I understand the concept of executors but i am having some trouble understanding executors in kotlin. Maybe it's the syntax not helping.

Let us look at the following example:

```
     private class AlwaysCallback(private val executor: (() -> Unit) -> Unit,
                                  private val cb: Progress.() -> Unit) : Callback {
         override fun execute(progress: Progress) {
             executor {
                 progress.cb()
             }
         }
     }
```

If i understood correctly, an executor `( () -> Unit ) -> Unit` is a vessel for a closure. A block of code that is to be executed. I am not sure if this is true or it is just a vessel for a anonymous function.

Another thing is, could someone explain the syntax:`( () -> Unit ) -> Unit` ?

I have read the kotlin documentation, read kotlin source code and tried to google it but i am really struggling to understand this. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but what is it that you are trying to achieve? Could you explain or give a working Java code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`() -> Unit` is a function that takes nothing as argument, and returns nothing. For example, `Runnable.run()` is such a function. You can see such a function as a task.

So, `(() -> Unit) -> Unit` is a function that takes such a function as argument, and returns nothing. For example, `Executor.execute(Runnable)` is such a function. It's thus a function that takes a task as argument (most probably, to execute that task, now, later, once or several times).

Here's an example which defines a function creating what I just called a task, and another function returning an executor, i.e. a function that executes the task:

```
fun createTask(): () -> Unit {
    return {
        println("Hello world")
    }
}

fun createExecutor() : (() -> Unit) -> Unit {
    return { task: () -> Unit ->
        println("I'm going to execute the task...")
        task()
        println("I'm going to execute the task a second time...")
        task()
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val task = createTask()
    val executor = createExecutor()
    executor(task)
}
```

Note that I'm still learning Kotlin myself, so I still struggle with the syntax and the concepts, too.

Comment: Unit is explained here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions.

Comment: I read the documentation for the Unit keywork. I understand it now. Your example is fairly good, however, i still struggle bit when i try to imagine that but with arguments and/or return values. Another thing, does `createTask()` return a closure?

Comment: Yes. But I think the appropriate Kotlin term is a "function literal", aka lambda expression. It would really become a closure if it "captured" a local variable defined before the function literal, which is not the case here.